# How can I combine several numpy arrays to a single string representation?

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have a few numpy arrays:

```
X = np.array([0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1])
Y = np.array([0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1])
Z = np.array([0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1])
```

How can I use those to generate this:

```
array(['0_0_0',
       '0_0_1',
       '0_1_0',
       '0,1,1',
       ...
      ], dtype='|S1')
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

```
np.array(["_".join(row.astype('|S1')) for row in np.concatenate([[X], [Y], [Z]]).T])
```

Comment: Any way to avoid the loop? I'm doing this over some pretty big arrays, so I'm trying to make it as efficient as possible.